# The Selection Cannot Be Run Any Server Eclipse Websphere

Tags: eclipse, websphere, ibm-wdt

I have been having issues on my project on Eclipse. It keeps on showing me the error message "The selection cannot be run on any server".

1. I have already checked the project facets and Dynamic Web Module, Java, Javascript, Websphere Web (Coexistence and Extended) are checked.
2. I have Websphere checked on runtimes as well.
3. Websphere settings are fine as well.
4. There are no errors on the project.
5. It runs on Tomcat without issues, but when I try to run it on WebSphere Application Server I get an error.
6. When I click on Server > Add & Remove > I am not able to find my project there.
7. I have already reinstalled Websphere.
8. I have already researched about the issue and mostly have done the steps in there.

I'm hoping someone could help me and enlighten as to why this is happening. Thank you!

[image: Project Facets]

[image: Server Status]

[image: Add and Remove]

Comment: If you're able to select WebSphere in Targeted Runtimes, I can't imagine why you can't actually run it. Which versions of WebSphere & Eclipse? Is the server able to start from Eclipse?

Comment: Yes, that's why I am also running out of ideas to fix this. I'm using Eclipse Photon and WebSphere 8.5.5 for Photon. And yes, the WebSphere server runs on Eclipse, I just can't run this project.

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0JfA.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2qGN.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AMnp.png

here are the pictures. it may help

Comment: Suggest you edit the question to add those images. It'll be easier for folks to see them all at once.

Comment: It is a Java 8 version of WebSphere, correct? What fixpack?

Comment: @dbreaux I have tried to edit the post to show the images, but it seems like it doesn't appear? Maybe because I'm new here? 

Yes, it's a Java 8 version. I haven't downloaded any fix packs yet, but I'm currently downloading the fix pack 13. I'll probably try again after that. I just hope it works or there's some improvements. Thanks again!